# How could I attach a piece of GET/POST data to every single request coming into the server for logged in users?

Tags: jquery, django

I want to have an input element at the to of my webpage that contains some global settings for a logged in user.  How could I attach this piece of data to every single GET/POST and AJAX request that comes in from my web application?  I wanted to tack this onto an existing site that has a lot of code already.

Cookies aren't what I'm looking for, because you couldn't have two different cookies for the same site in different tabs/windows of the same application (an HTML input could have different values for the same logged in user in two different tabs/windows.)

UPDATE: To clarify, the feature I want is to bridge two different modes in the same browser and let the user switch between the two modes via an option menu.  The current mode would affect everything the user does even down to short/small Ajax requests (every request into the system would need to know what mode the browser window is in.)  So two different tabs in the same browser would behave very differently from each other if they are in different modes.

Comment: What exactly is the result you are trying to achieve?  So that we can understand why you can't use sessions.
Keep in mind that if you want a different state in two different browser tabs/windows for the same user logged in, then it is not a 'global setting' anymore. Also if it's in GET, the user can modify the URL.
I'm curious as to what kind of functionality do you need, so I can give better info.

Comment: I don't think there is any appropriate answer that can be given for this question, in that to make a decision on "how" would require more detail about the specifics of the application, or at least specific differences between "modes". Hidden fields, extra data in an AJAX POST|GET request, etc, are **all** applicable answers. Good job everyone.

Comment: Are the HTTP requests stateless?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your app has two modes.  Let's call
them red and blue.  User opens window 1 and selects red.  User
then opens window 2 and selects blue.  If you merely used
sessions, then if the user goes back to window 1 and clicks
anything, the result would be blue because the previous click
was blue, even though window 1 is red.

I suggest using mod_rewrite (or an equivalent on non-Apache
servers) to modify the URL to indicate the mode.

Incoming request for

```
example.com/red/yourscript  ==>  example.com/yourscript?mode=red
example.com/blue/yourscript  ==> example.com/yourscript?mode=blue
```

If all the links and forms on your page are relative and not
absolute, the URLs should have the mode info in them.

That is, if the page URL is

```
example.com/red/yourscript
```

then links on the page that look like this

```
<form action="anotherscript">
```

will have a URL of

```
example.com/red/anotherscript
```

Another way would be to use subdomains

```
red.example.com/yourscript  ==>  example.com/yourscript
blue.example.com/yourscript  ==> example.com/yourscript
```

You would not need mod_rewrite if you configure your server to serve both subdomains from the same real location.

Using the subdomains would allow you to extract the mode from
the http_referer field of each incoming request and you
wouldn't need to add the query string.

Lastly, add absolute links to explicitly change the mode.

```
<a href="http://example.com/red/changemode">Click here to go to RED mode</a>
<a href="http://example.com/blue/changemode">Click here to go to BLUE mode</a>
```

Comment: This approach will only work if the Web Application is stateless, i.e. each HTTP request is atomic and causing a request to be repeated will not break the application.  If you application is stateful this won't work.

Comment: Martin Spamer, yes, it will work even if the application is stateful.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a classic case of hidden fields. You'd need some way of knowing who the user is when you send the HTML out, obviously. NB this is in no way secure at all, the user could potentially send whatever data they wanted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="fieldvalue" />
```

Comment: If you chose this route you'd need to use javascript to make sure that any links which are clicked also submit the form.

Comment: How could I make sure this input is attached to every single web request?  What about an AJAX request that is tied to some small part of the screen?

Comment: I was assuming you can't do this with sessions (which are usually tied to cookies). If you can use sessions, you should. They're pretty much the only way you're going to remember who your client is (without a lot of pain re-inventing the wheel).

Sessions can also be done with URL re-writing, no cookies required (depending on your framework). As Byron Whitlock says, passing variables around certainly isn't the 'correct' way of keeping track of people. And if you have the session and store this info there, there's no need to pass data back and forward through forms.

Answer (score 3):

What about making different subdomains for your 2 different models?

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using [sessions](http://www.php.net/session) for persisting user data? With a session, you can persist the data across posts, keep session data depending on the page.

Comment: A session wouldn't keep track of two different open browser windows or tabs having a different state.

Comment: Sure you can, just check the referrer, and store session data based on that. You would need to create some sort of click stream data to handle transitions form one page to another. Again, this will be more robust than trying to persist form variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and [template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to sounds a bit like this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458829/modify-address-in-django-middleware/1460317#1460317) I answered.

You can do changes like this in middleware (see the link above) but it doesn't really make sense. It's more likely that you want to change the session data.

Following are the different options I see that you have.

1) GET

Changing the GET data would effectively refirect the user as it changes the address in the URL and this sends the user to a new page. So, you can edit this but it will redirect the user each time they load a page! Bad idea. Otherwise you could somehow manage your URL's so each link adds something in but it still doesn't really make sense as a user thats not logged in could add this to the URL if they know what it is. Again, bad idea.

2) POST

The post information is what is sent to you from the browser, besides cleaning the data its not really the right place to add and replace information.

3) SESSION

You can find out about Django sessions [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). This is a technique used in a number of places, in particular in django.contrib.auth. The session is used to verify the user and modify the request [object](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py). This may be what you want to do, here you could either modify the session or change the request object - however, I'd be wary of making too many changes to request as it could cause conflicts with other apps or future django changes/additions.

4) jQuery (since you tagged this as jQuery) too

You could do something hacky and nasty like this in javascript, if you insist.

```
$("a").each(function()
   { 
      this.href += "?newdata=1";
   });
```

However I wouldn't recommend this and it doesn't take into account there already being GET data (if there is). I just add it to show you another option as I'm not quite sure what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a custom template render method ?

```
def myrender(request, model, data={}):
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    data['user'] = request.user
    return render_to_response(model, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then create a [templatetag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to render this in your pages ?

I use this technique to display login info and current page

Comment: you can also use this to add data to your ajax responses. i dont understand what you mean by 'links'.

Comment: RequestContext by itself contains data that are added by sitewide-definable "context processors", so it would be sufficient to use that and then just add context_instance=RequestContext(request) to render_to_response().

Answer (score 0):

This may be totally useless, depending on what your 'modes' are:
What if the server returns the same page every time, and the modes are applied by javascript. The JS could alter styles and DOM, or issue differing AJAX requests, depending on the mode.

Answer (score 0):

This can elegantly be accomplished with [jquery.Metadata](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata). You'd simply need to push a form on each page with one element containing all your data that you'll append to each form once it's getting submitted:

On each page you would have:

```
<form name="_settings" type="post">
    <p>
        <input name="_settings" type="hidden" value="{preference: 'chocolate', 
             displayListSize: 30, something: 'else'}" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Now you can do something with similar fashion:

```
// Bind to the submit event of each form
$('form').submit(function () {
    // Append all input fields from `_settings`
    $(this).append('form[name="settings"]:input');

    return true;
});
```

Or append the settings to a specific form, or all forms if none specified:

```
function appendSettings(form) {
     if (form)
         $(form).append('form[name="_settings"]:input');
     else
         $('form').append('form[name="_settings"]:input');
}
```

...after which you can submit the form as part of an AJAX request *(that may not have triggered the forms `submit` event otherwise)*

EDIT:

As for GET/POST request via links:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    href = $(this).attr('href');

    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!href.match('?'))
        // Change the form's action to the link's reference
        $('form[name="_settings"']).attr('action', href).submit();
    else {
        /* Sanitize the form's data into GET paramaters and
           change the window's location*/
    }   
});
```

If you wouldn't like to use jquery.Metadata, you can make as many hidden fields with name/value pairs on the `_settings` form and it would still work. I've used it as a good example of portable data since both JS and Django can speak JSON.

Also, I'm assuming too much by writing a jQuery example, but I'm somewhat hoping that your already using some framework and that this could neatly be translated to the framework of your choice.

Comment: I am using jquery and this sounds like a great start.  Is there a way I could attach this metadta to small AJAX requests?

Comment: `$.ajax({url: "/some-page", data: {some: "data", other: "data", _settings: $('form[name="_settings"]:input').metadata()}, success: handleResponse});`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and use it with [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) to add some custom data for your generic template (and then use [inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) to get this to all other templates, as Hank Gay says).

Answer (score 0):

I have an application which stores the entire session this way right now, I've introduced specialized ajax wrappers for all of my server calls.

```
$.myget = function (url, data, k) {
 $.get(url, $.extend(read_session_data(), data), k);
}
```

`read_session_data` is left as an exercise for the reader.

In addition to managing this issue, it make it easier for me to handle errors in a controlled (and concise) manner.